# res.json not working inside callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently working on an API endpoint.

Upon posting the data to the endpoint `/authenticate`, I use the `plaidClient.getAuthUser` function to get the user's account information, and then I'm trying to use `res.json` to return the account data.

After running this:

`accounts = JSON.stringify(res.accounts);
console.log('accounts: ' + accounts);`

I successfully am able to see the array of dictionaries containing the account information.

However, when I attempt to use `res.json({accounts: accounts})`, I get the error:

`res.json({accounts: accounts});
    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function`

When I try to run `res.send(accounts)` in place of res.json, I receive the same error:

`res.send({accounts: accounts});
    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Here's my code:

`var public_token = "";
var access_token = "";
var accounts = [];`

```
 app.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
    console.log('post');
    public_token = req.body.public_token;
    console.log(public_token);
    console.log('plaid: ' + app.client);
    server.client.exchangeToken(public_token, function (err, res) {
        console.log('exchange');
        if (err) {
            //Handle Error
            console.log('exchange-error');
        }
        else {
            //We now have exchanged our Plaid access token.
            //Store it somewhere persistent
            //Access token is used to make API calls
            access_token = res.access_token;
            console.log('access_token: ' + access_token);

            server.client.getAuthUser(access_token, function (err, res) {
                if (err != null) {
                    //handle error
                    console.log('authorization-error');
                }
                else {
                    // Our response will hold an array of accounts for this user, containing account names,
                    // balances, account and routing numbers.
                    accounts = JSON.stringify(res.accounts);
                    console.log('accounts: ' + accounts);

                    //Return account data
                    res.json({accounts: accounts});
                }
            });
        }
    });
     res.contentType('application/json');
     res.send(accounts);
});
```

};`

Also, when I run the final 2 lines:

`res.contentType('application/json');
res.send(accounts);`

The account variable defaults back to it's initial value of `[]`

I think this may be a closure issue but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 app.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
    console.log('post');
    public_token = req.body.public_token;
    console.log(public_token);
    console.log('plaid: ' + app.client);
    server.client.exchangeToken(public_token, function (err, ***res***) {
```

you have overwritten res in your second callback

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.